# How to call javascript function on initial page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a script that loads the country options from a list that I created. I would like to be able to only load it the initial time the page loads and not on each load afterwords. The problem is when I try to click a button and save the info, it reverts back to the beginning of the lists. What is the best window method to use for this? I looked at the alternate window methods and wasn't successful in finding the solution. Onloadstart also didn't seem to work.

Also my script is on my User Control page, so I would prefer not to call the function from codebehind.

```
       window.onload = function () {

       var countryElement = document.getElementById('countryId');

       var listOfCountries = ["Select Country","Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antigua &amp; Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas"
, "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "British Virgin Islands"
, "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Congo", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica"
, "Cote D Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cruise Ship", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea"
, "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Polynesia", "French West Indies", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana"
, "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India"
, "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Isle of Man", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyz Republic", "Laos", "Latvia"
, "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Mauritania"
, "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia"
, "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palestine", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal"
, "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Satellite", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles"
, "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "South Korea", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St Kitts &amp; Nevis", "St Lucia", "St Vincent", "St. Lucia", "Sudan"
, "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Timor L'Este", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad &amp; Tobago", "Tunisia"
, "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks &amp; Caicos", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands (US)"
, "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"];

       countryElement.options.length = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i < listOfCountries.length; i++) {
           countryElement.options[i] = new Option(listOfCountries[i]);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using server-side code mixed with client-side code. When you click your button, you cause a postback to the server, which delivers the page to the client again, causing the `onload` code you have in that page to run again, with the same values it had last time.

You should use the IsPostBack property to determine if the page is loading for the very first time and only include that client-side script when it is.

Comment: How would I load the script if it's in my user control page? I thought about doing this but couldn't figure it out